# pipenv unable to install cysystemd but pip does

Tags: pipenv, cysystemd, python-systemd

Tried to install package cysystemd using:
'pipenv install cysystemd'
It created the 'cysystemd' in the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock, but nothing was installed.
Tried:
'pip install cysystemd'
and that worked.
Is this a bug in pipenv? (or is my command wrong?)